# Trying to convert a number to binary form

Tags: ruby

I wrote a simple program which works:

```
a = 4.to_s(2) 

puts a.reverse
```

I want to be able to change it based on input from the user in the terminal. This is what I wrote:

```
puts 'Please enter a number you would like to see expressed in binary form'

i = gets.chomp

b = i.to_s(2)

puts b
```

This is the error that I keep getting:

```
`to_s': wrong number of arguments(1 for 0) (ArgumentError)
```

Comment: change it means what ? `4` or `2` ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit, sorry, posted the question before it was finished by accident. it's more complete now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're starting with a string, so you need to convert it:

```
i.to_i.to_s(2)
```

The `#to_s` method on a string doesn't take any arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need the `chomp` method, `#to_i` will take care of it.

Write it as:

```
puts 'Please enter a number you would like to see expressed in binary form'

i = gets.to_i
b = i.to_s(2)

puts b
```

You are calling `to_s` on an string, not on `integer` as you are thinking, because `Kernel#gets` always gives you a *String* object.

First, convert it to `Fixnum`, then call [`Fixnum#to_s`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Fixnum.html#method-i-to_s) on the `Fixnum` instance, which takes an *argument*, but [`String#to_s`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-to_s) doesn't accept *arguments*, which was why you got a complaint from Ruby.

Comment: thank you for such an through explanation. much appreciated! =)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to use `Fixnum#to_s` but in your program `gets.chomp` returns a string, so you actually call `String#to_s`

You can could do:

```
i = gets.chomp.to_i
```

Comment: Why would you think `Fixnum#to_s` was redefined?

Comment: `(6*9).to_s(13)` returns `"42"` which makes this method pretty handy.

Comment: It is the ultimate method.